# Feed dialog inside page

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an application that runs inside a iframe on facebook canvas page. As it is a game, I would like to make it able to allow users to share their score, for this purpose, I've tryed the following:

```
FB.ui({
  app_id: '000000000000000000',
  method: 'feed',
  display: 'page',
  name: 'Dialog Name',
  caption: 'Caption for dialog',
  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'
});
```

What I want is that when this code get running, a dialog appears over my page, however, instead of it, it always tries to open a window, to be even worst, all of my parameters are ignored in the window.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the display as `iframe`, not `page` (`page` is the default setting anyway, I don't know why you are specifying it).

You can find more information here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Also, you shouldn't need the `app_id` parameter (most of the time the JS SDK will automatically add it for you).

EDIT

Here's what I use:

```
  FB.ui({
      display: "iframe",
      method: "feed",
      name: "",
      link: "",
      picture: "",
      caption: "",
      description: "",
      message: "",
      actions: {"name":"","link":""}
    },function(response){});
  }
```

Comment: Earlier I tried it, but it failed (probably because I testes it in a isolated page, not in my real application. Now I modified it to `iframe` and removes the `app_id`. Now, the dialog appears, however, with an error message: `API Error Code: 102`
`API Error Description: Session key invalid or no longer valid`
`Error Message: Iframe dialogs must be called with a session key`, what can it be?

Comment: My application loads though PHP, then I loaded the Javascript SDK just in order to show the like buttons and show this dialog, but then, I don't know how to retrieve `the session key`.

Comment: Are you using the latest PHP SDK (v3.1.1)?  If you are, then you shouldn't need to provide one.

Comment: As the PHP SDK does not have good documentation, all the work is done as the [Getting Started tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/). I also tried using your parameters, but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this through the parameter "display: 'popup'" so change it to:

```
FB.ui({
  display: "popup",
  method: "feed",
  name: "",
  link: "",
  picture: "",
  caption: "",
  description: "",
  message: "",
  actions: {"name":"","link":""}
},function(response){});
```

}